# Qt connect doesn't recognize with lambda expression

Tags: c++, qt, lambda, slot

I'm designed a `QTableWidget` with `QPushButton`, I would like to connect these buttons with a slot to hide some rows.

I'm using a lambda expression to pass a number of a row. But the compiler doesn't recognized this expression :

```
connect(this->ui->tableWidget->cellWidget(i,0),&QPushButton::clicked,[this,i]{hideRows(i);});
```

I have this error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'SoftwareUdpater::MainWidget::connect(QWidget*, void (QAbstractButton::*)(bool), SoftwareUdpater::MainWidget::displayTable()::<lambda(int)>)'
```

- The function `hideRows(int)` is declared as a function. And, as a slot, it doesn't work,
- `CONFIG += c++11` is added in pro file,
- My class `MainWidget` inherits from `QWidget`,
- `Q_OBJECT` is added in the header.

So I don't udnerstand why `connect()` is not recognized by *Qt 5.9.1 MinGw 32bit*.

Edit: `[this,i]()` instead of `[this](const int i)` for the lambda expression

Comment: in addition to what the answer says, you most likely want to capture the `i` by value instead of taking it as a parameter `connect(this->ui->tableWidget->cellWidget(i,0),&QPushButton::clicked,[this,i](){hideRows(i);});`

Comment: using both `[this,i]` and `(int i)` doesn't make much sense. Additionally it seems like you might need to downcast your QWidget* to QPushbutton* `connect((QPushButton*)this->ui->tableWidget->cellWidget(i,0),&QPushButton::clicked,[this,i](){hideRows(i);});`. This is assuming that it always is a QPushbutton.

Comment: That error message means, there is no such `connect` function, which takes those parameters. Most likely reason is, you are somehow not building with C++11, or you are somehow building with Qt4, or something else external like that. Perhaps you should edit the question to add complete error message, with list of what candidates were found. Also add the compile command used to build that file.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the *::<lambda(int)>* part at the end of the error message.  That seems to be suggesting that the compiler thinks your lambda *accepts* an integer parameter even though it simply captures *this* and *i*.  Are you absolutely sure the code posted is the code that's causing the error?  It works just fine for me.

Comment: Try explicitly using the static method: `QObject::connect(....)`. @G.M. Question was edited it seems, and now it looks like the code and error message are not in sync...

Comment: You really should pass `this` as a context object (third argument, before the lambda) if you're capturing `this` - otherwise the lambda may be called after `this` has been destroyed.

Comment: @hyde My bad -- I should've checked the edits.  But, I agree, it does appear the code/error are out of sync.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your connection is wrong. You can't connect a function that doesn't take parameters (clicked()) with a function that takes parameters (your lambda). To verify that this is the case, just do this:

```
connect(this->ui->tableWidget->cellWidget(i,0),&QPushButton::clicked,[this](){});
```

And see that it will compile. You have to make your design in such a way that signals and slots are compatible.

Also avoid using lambdas in signals and slots. Read the caveats [here](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax).

Comment: I wouldn't go as far as saying "avoid lambdas" - just know how they work with signals and slots and use them correctly. Besides, since Qt 5.2 where you can now pass a context object to be used to break the connection to the lambda, the biggest caveat is gone.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Agreed. But I'm considering that the guy doesn't understand anything about connections (yet), and hoping the link will explain why he should be careful with lambdas.

Comment: Thanks. With your code, I have the same error. The connection are not recognized.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist `C:\Users\lbraud\SW-Provider-GUI\SoftwareUpdater\src\mainwidget.cpp:66: error: no matching function for call to 'SoftwareUdpater::MainWidget::connect(QWidget*, void (QAbstractButton::*)(bool), SoftwareUdpater::MainWidget::displayTable()::<lambda()>)'
          connect(this->ui->tableWidget->cellWidget(i,0),&QPushButton::clicked,[](){});`

Comment: @LilianBr Sorry, I don't know what the problem is. Try to use  normal signals and slots.

Comment: I will use a table to save the position of the button and its pointer, so I will be able to use a normal connection.

Comment: If you really can't make it work with a lambda, you can still use the [QSignalMapper](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalmapper.html) to solve your problem I guess, better than using a custom table.

Comment: The problem is that `QWidget *` does not define `clicked`, but`QPushButton *` does. Check my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I was reading your comments on the accepted answer and noticed the root of the problem: This error is being thrown because the effective type of the object  — as supplied to `QObject::connect`; i.e  `QWidget` in your case — does not define the referenced signal `QPushButton::clicked`.

What likely happened is that the `QPushButton` pointer was cast into a `QWidget` and then *that* pointer was given to `connect` instead of the original which defines the signal.

Cast the pointer back to a `QPushButton *` and the error should go away.